Difference between Option-Implied Skewness/Kurtosis and Historical Realised Skewness Kurtosis
As the title states, what is the difference between option-implied skewness/kurtosis and historical realized skewness/kurtosis?
It is often the case that option-implied volatility is higher than historical realized volatility by an amount that is known as the volatility risk premium i.e. the additional compensation that is required by investors for bearing tail risk, more as a manifestation of their risk averse preferences.
Is there a similar thing for skewness and kurtosis? Skewness/Kurtosis risk premium? What are the common signs? Is it usually positive/negative in calm/crisis regimes? - similar to how the volatility risk premium is positive/negative in calm/crisis regimes.
Any peer-reviewed articles or opinions are very welcome.

Implied skewness is the third moment implied by options. Realized skewness is, well, what has been realized. Yes I think there are premia in skewness and kurtosis as well. You can start here https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1807804 for example.

Also take a look at this recent article on skewness premium: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3968542 and last but not least a recent article by Lorenzo Ravagli https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4687408

Neuberger and Payne (2021)  document a negative skewness at the daily frequency which also extrapolates to longer horizons. So even long-term investors are not exempt from the skewness risk that exists in the short term. They argue that the two main components of skewness are outliers and the negative correlation between past returns and the current variance of stock returns (the latter is the most important factor in the US).
A large literature in behavioral finance has found that investors have a preference  for positively skewed stocks ("lottery-like stocks"). Kumar (2008) finds that the demand for these stocks increases in crises. According to standard mean-variance utility functions, skewness should not be priced. Barberis and Huang (2008) show that using cumulative prospect theory can generating pricing of idiosyncratic skewness.

Hi, can you explain why standard utility theory does not price skewness? Or do you mean  a mean-variance-optimizer does not price skewness?

Thanks for the interesting references!

@Kermittfrog Sorry, I meant mean-variance-optimizer doesn't apply here. You can come up with a utility function that prices skewness, but those are not common. CARA, CRRA, Epstein-Zin, etc. will not price skewness.
